# Drupal GraphQL - Query Single Entity from URL

Tags: graphql, drupal-8

Is it possible to get an article(single entity) using the Url Alias (entityUrl.path)?

I am using https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql

I can do a bulk query for all the articles, do I then filter those results?

Thanks

```
query GetArticles {
  nodeQuery(filter: {conditions: [{field: "type", value: "article"}]}) {
    Articles: entities {
      entityId
      entityLabel
      entityUrl {
        path
        routed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
query ($path: String!) {
  route:route(path: $path) {
    ... on EntityCanonicalUrl {
      entity {
        ... on Node {
          nid
          entityLabel
          body{
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```